# Spring WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer with Artemis 2.6.3 Multicast (topic) not working

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, activemq-artemis

Artemis mutilcast address and queue not having the expected behaviour.
My idea is to create groups or specific messaging to a user that can have multiple websocket sessions (web, android, etc...). Server will publish notification to artemis multicast address and all subscribers should receive the notification. In the curren scenarion I just force user 'luislaves00' and create more than one session. In artemis I can see 2 consumers (not sure how Message Broker Relay from spring does it's job), but the consumers behave like a round robin and not publisher-subscriber. With the in memory broker from Spring it works fine but it's not durable, so when there's no subscriber connected the messages are droped.
Here is the code I'm using:

Client side part:

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/notification-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    var headers = {
        // todo: server will handle this logic
        'client-id': 'luisalves00',
        'durable-subscription-name': 'luisalves00',
        'id' : 'luisalves00'
    };
    stompClient.connect(headers, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        // todo: server will handle this logic
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/notification/username' + 'luisalves00', function(notification) {
            showNotification(JSON.parse(notification.body).content);
        }, headers);
    });
}
```

Broker Relay config:

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        // Artemis ->
        // tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("127.0.0.1").setRelayPort(61613);
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        //config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        logger.info("Registering the stomp endpoints.");

        registry.addEndpoint("/notification-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

    }
```

Server dummy notification producer:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20000)
public void scheduleTaskWithFixedDelay() {
    final Notification message = new Notification(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + " -> "  + dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
    try {
        final String user = "luisalves00";
        logger.info("Creating msg={}", message);
        final Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("subscription-id", user);
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/notification/username/" + user, message, headers);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }
}
```

When the client subscribe artemis creates address and persistent queue with this parameters:

```
Addesses: 
id=2147496008 name=/topic/notification/group1/ routingType=[MULTICAST] queueCount=1

Queue
id=2147496011 
name=group1.group1 
address=/topic/notification/group1/ 
routingType=MULTICAST
durable=true
maxConsumers-1
purgeOnNoConsumers=false 
consumerCount=0
```

Comment: When you say, "In artemis I can see 2 consumers..." To what queue are those 2 consumers connected? If they are connected to the same queue then they will receive messages round-robin (since they will share the messages placed in the queue). If you want both consumers to receive the messages sent to the address then there should be 2 queues on the address with 1 consumer each. It sounds to me like your 2 consumers are creating a durable subscription with the same client-id and subscription name which means they will share the durable subscription queue.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Yesterday I re-read the whole documentation again I understood "with the same client-id and subscription name". Each client need a need a unique client-id and I was using luisalve00 for both. I need to do something like luisallves00_1 and luisalves00_2 so it creates 2 queues. The confusing part is the routingType=MULTICAST in the queue. It behaves like a Q and not like a Topic so I don't understand it. Nevertheless, with this implementation it's possible to create consumer groups to do load balancing, which seems nice.

Comment: Queues bound to an address can be either anycast or multicast.  Anytime a message is sent to an address it is placed in *one* of the anycast queues (using round-robin if there are > 1 anycast queues) and/or *all* of the multicast queues.  For any queue there can be 1 or more consumers.  Consumers share the message in a queue.  This architecture easily allows for a wide variety of delivery semantics.

Comment: Yes, seems a bit like kafka. Anyway got it to work as I wanted, but maintaining the state (number slots) for the client ids seems a bit overwhelming. The side effect is that I can control the number of subscribers for topic in the application. I think spring does something automagic with the websocket session id, but this will create a new durable queue for each "random" session number, which doens't seem a good idea as it will grow a lot and not sure how it can be cleared out. By the way which stomp header can I use to manage the message expiricy? I guess is ttl, but not sure.

Comment: There certainly is a danger of creating a durable subscription and then forgetting about it as any message sent to the address may accumulate in the subscription. Read more about deleting durable subscriptions at https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/stomp.html#durable-subscriptions. Use the `expires` header to control message expiration. This header uses "Unix time" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the durable work you must use:

```
'client-id': '<some unique identifier for each client>'
'durable-subscription-name': 'tech-news'
```

For my implementation I stopped using durable, as the idea of the notification is to be delivered when created (low latency). If the consumer is not connected it can connection to an historic database to fetch old messages that he did not received when connected. 
If your really want to make it durable I suggest to handle in server side the 'client-id' and durable-subscription-name' for the connected user. If the user has no on going session, then create a durable queue. The next session he creates should be non durable, as they will receive the same messages as the durable one. If the first session dies, he still receive messages on the other sessions. When all die and he reconnect, it's going to be the first session again and he'll receive all messages that were not delivered on the durable queue (probably some he already received on the non durable ones), but he will have the history of all messages (that as said before I think it should be handled in other way).